# Calibre server and FB2 mime type in feed

Tags: calibre, fb2

I run calibre-server in my local network that every one family member can access our home library.

Calibre server returns FB2 files as of type "text/fb2+xml" in the feed.

I have troubles to download FB2 files on my PocketBook Touch Lux 4 because it says that "text/fb2+xml" is unsupported format.

Here is a list of available formats to download in calibre feed:

[image: calibre server feed]

Here is how my PocketBook shows available formats:

[image: Select format to download]

Is there a solution to make possible that PocketBook understand FB2 book format from Calibre server feed?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution how to patch Calibre server to allow PocketBook to "understand" books in FB2 format:

```
--- a/resources/mime.types      2020-09-20 00:05:56.394886069 +0000
+++ b/resources/mime.types      2020-09-20 00:06:06.814962147 +0000
@@ -1362,7 +1362,7 @@
 
 ## calibre specific mime types
 
-text/fb2+xml                               fb2
+application/fb2                            fb2
 text/x-sony-bbeb+xml                       lrs
 application/x-sony-bbeb                    lrf lrx
 application/adobe-page-template+xml        xpgt
```

I tested this patch with PocketBook and FBReader for android and both "understand" the format.

*I didn't test another reading apps with this change in Calibre server.*